# Ipv6 Adresses from the same Home?

Tags: networking, routes, ipv6

I need to figure out if these ipv6 adresses are from the same home (see below). I‘m not sure because while researching I did read that the first 3 or the first 4 hex-Numbers are uniquely assigned to a user.

Case 1: log in from a windows device on 30.12.2021 to google account 1 with the ip **2003:c5:3f02:6001:e88d:cf9d:ca23:59ff**

Case 2: log in from an android smartphone on 02.01.2022 to google account 1 with the ip **2003:c5:3f02:6001:e88d:cf9d:ca23:59ff (-> same home)**

Case 3: log in from a windows device on 30.12.2021 to google account 2 with the ip **2003:c5:3f02:6064:6815:bd58:386d:6337 (-> same home?!)**

### Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first 4 octects 2003:c5:3f02:6001 are assigned by your router which is called a /64 the last part are generated by your device and changes every couple of hours or they could be static. Each device on your router now gets its own IP address.